# Take automated backup of Digital ocean server on aws s3 bucket on daily basis

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, backup, digital-ocean, database-backups

I have digital ocean droplet with files and MySQL database and want to backup this on aws s3 bucket on a daily basis i.e every midnight

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please share what you have already tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Login to your Droplet using root access**

**1.// first install awscli**

```
apt install awscli
```

**2. //Create S3 bucket and provide below details**

```
aws configure

AWS Access Key ID [None]: {enter your access key id}         
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: {enter your secret access key} 
Default region name [None]: {enter your preferred region}    
Default output format [None]: {enter your preferred format}
```

**3.// test the connection is working??**

```
aws s3 cp file.zip s3://{bucket_name}
```

**4.// create actual script (backup.sh)**

```
#!/bin/sh

# Database credentials
DATABASE="database-name"
USERNAME="database_user"
PASSWORD="password"

# Directory to back up
SOURCE_DIR= Files_path_here

# Target
TARGET_DIR=/backup
TARGET_BUCKET= Bucket-name

# Output files
NOW=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
DB_OUTPUT=$TARGET_DIR/db.$NOW.sql.gz
FILES_OUTPUT=$TARGET_DIR/files.$NOW.zip

# Back up files
zip -r $FILES_OUTPUT $SOURCE_DIR

# Back up database
mysqldump -u $USERNAME -p"$PASSWORD" $DATABASE --single-transaction | gzip > $DB_OUTPUT

# Upload to S3
aws s3 cp $DB_OUTPUT s3://$TARGET_BUCKET
aws s3 cp $FILES_OUTPUT s3://$TARGET_BUCKET

# Remove files older than 14 days
find $TARGET_DIR -type f -mtime +14 | xargs rm -f
```

**5.// give permissions**

```
chmod 700 backup.sh
```

**6.// convert this bash file (i.e backup.sh) to linux compatible**

```
sed -i -e 's/\r$//' backup.sh
```

**7.// Test the backup by running it from the command line:**

```
./backup.sh
```

**8.// the following command to edit the crontab**

```
crontab -e
```

**9.Add the following line at the bottom:**

```
0 22 * * * /path/to/backup.sh
```